# Sql stored procedure to update empty column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery

This is my table

```
  FundId  Fund   Industry State    Column1
     1     1        2      NSW             
     2     1        2      ACT         
     3     1        2      VIC          
     4     1        2      NSW         
     5     1        2      ACT         
     6     1        2      VIC         
     7     1        2      NSW          
     8     1        2      ACT         
     9     1        2      VIC
```

Currently the Column1 is empty which is a calculated column. It is calculated as

```
   Column1: fund*5
```

Below is the query to calculate Column1

```
 SELECT Fund,
           Industry,
           State,
           Fund * 5 AS Column1
    FROM fundDetails
```

The query is working fine. But i want to updated the empty Column1 using stored procedure.

How can I update the `column1` .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please google for MSSQL stored procedure structure.

Comment: If the relationship is *always* that `column1` is equal to `Fund * 5` then my primary recommendation would be to not *store* that anywhere. If you do want to store it (and the relationship always holds), I'd recommend a computed column. In general, don't store data that can be computed, or if you must store it, use database features to ensure that it's *consistent* with the base data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_Upd_fundDetails
AS
BEGIN
      UPDATE fundDetails
      SET Column1 = Fund*5
END
```

Comment: thanks what if the value is coming from two different tables

Comment: But your requirement is to update the colunm1 with the other column which is existed in the same table know, if your requirement is different then please explain that, so that I can explain/help you

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can update it :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateColumn1 @Value int  
As
Begin
Update fundDetails set Column1 = Fund*@value 
END 
GO
```

where @value is a parameter to pass to stored procedure
to execute it use:
          EXEC dbo.UpdateColumn1 @Value = 5

Comment: hi A.Tarhini, User want to update Colunm1 with the caluclated value existed in Fund Column, so no need to pass parameter to the stored procedure.

Comment: hi john, i take into consideration the case when he want to multiply fund by a number other than 5.

Answer (score 0):

First create procedure as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_update_column1
AS
BEGIN
 UPDATE fundDetails set  SET Column1 = Fund*5
END
```

Now call stored procedure as

```
usp_update_column1 // or
EXEC usp_update_column1 // or
EXECUTE usp_update_column1
```

Comment: Hi Suman, It is not recomondable to create Stored Procedure with starting SP_....... Because It cause in the execution delay. You can google it if you want more info on this.

Answer (score 0):

```html
-- =============================================
-- Author:  <Jay Raj Mishra>
-- Create date: <Tuesday 25-10-2016 11:57 AM>
-- Description: <update the column1 Field>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_FundUpdate
@FundID INT=NULL,
@Column1 MONEY=NULL
AS
BEGIN
 UPDATE fundDetails SET Column1=@Column*5 WHERE FundId=@FundID
END
GO
```

to call SP - usp_FundUpdate @FundID =1,@Column1 =2